# New date format from Twitter

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, twitter, date-format

So, I am implementing twitter via twitter widget pro into a wordpress theme. I'm wanting to date the tweets differently from wordpress and from the widgets formats. I want to follow twitters date format of 5h, 23h, or 3 Mar. All I've been able to find is how to do the "created _ ago" "about _ old" etc... I just want to use the xh if within 24 hours, otherwise use the day and month abbreviation. I really don't know php or too much js, so any help is very very much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to show `02 hours, 1 days` ago type time duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP [DateTime](http://bd.php.net/DateTime) and [DateInterval](http://bd.php.net/DateInterval) classes,

```
$dt1 = new DateTime("2012-02-10 10:32:22");
$dt2 = new DateTime();
$diff = $dt2->diff($dt1);
echo $diff->format("%Y years, %m months, %d days, %H hours, %I minuts, %s seconds ago");
/// 00 years, 1 months, 18 days, 08 hours, 26 minuts, 51 seconds ago
```

If you dont want to echo `00 years`, `00 months` etc then check `DateTime::y`, `DateTime::m` etc properties is 0. if zero dont echo them.  For example,

```
$format = "";
if ($diff->y > 0){
    $format.="%Y years,";
}
if ($diff->m > 0){
    $format.="%m months,";
}
...
// more conditions for hours, minutes, seconds

// echo the format
echo $diff->format($format);
```

Links of Interest,

1. [DateTime::__construct()](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)
2. [DateTime::diff()](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)
3. [DateInterval::format()](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: I guess I'm wondering more so how I can make it switch from showing the minutes... to then the hours, then to a date.

Comment: @user1298207, See I have update the answer. Its a matter of logic.

Comment: Thanks, I had the DateInterval, but hadn't seen the other two